# Error on AOT Compilation in Angular 2 for accessing formArray

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-aot

This is my formGroup

```
this.createOrderForm = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([])
    });
```

For Adding item on button click

```
 addItem() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.createOrderForm.controls['items'];
    const addrCtrl = this.initItem();
    control.push(addrCtrl);
  }
```

Item FormGroup is

```
initItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      est_delivery_date: [''],
      est_delivery_time: [''],
      parentServices: ['', Validators.required],
      services: [''],
      brands: ['', Validators.required],
      sizes: ['',Validators.required],
      products: ['', Validators.required],
      discounts: [''],
      is_express_delivery: [''],
      is_packing: [''],
      confirmed: [''],
      coupon: ['']
    });
  }
```

in my html

```
<div class="panel panel-default margin-20">
          <h4 class="form-group col-xs-12">Items</h4>
          <div formArrayName="items">
            <div *ngFor="let item of createOrderForm.get('items').controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading col-xs-12">
                <h5>Item {{i + 1}}</h5>
                <span class="ion-close pull-right" *ngIf="createOrderForm.get('items').controls.length > 1" (click)="removeItem(i)"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
                <createitem [pickup]="pickup_date" [group]="createOrderForm.get('items').controls[i]"></createitem>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am getting following Error on **AOT** compilation

**Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.**

Please help me figure out why i am getting this error, because it works perfectly in jit compiler.

Comment: It might help  you *ngFor="let item of createOrderForm.controls.items.controls; let i=index" or take a look at Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/hQ6RtzCfPosfQl4HlbZQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help but it will not compiled in aot.

Comment: did you checked Plnkr ?

Comment: Yes You are using controls in html. it throws error

Comment: May I know that you have placed form control in HTML ???

Comment: this line does not work in aot let address of myForm.controls.addresses.controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the template is the cause of problem for the Aot compilation.

```
createOrderForm.get('items').controls
```

You need to do this instead of having

```
let item of createOrderForm.get('items').controls
```

have something like this

```
let item of getItem(createOrderForm)
```

In the **component** use the following

```
  getItem(form){
    return form.get('items').controls
  }
```

Comment: don't know it's an right approach, but it works.. looks like fooling the aot compiler